# Split a column on the space into two columns

Tags: linux, awk

I have a large file ~9GB with each row in this format:

```
12345,6789,Jim Bob
```

My desired output is this:

```
12345,6789,Jim,Bob
```

How would I do this using `awk`. It seems to be the fastest way to process this and I am new when it comes to using the Terminal for such things. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk and regex to replace the first space with a comma:

```
$ awk '{sub(/ /,",")}1' file
12345,6789,Jim,Bob
```

or using awk and regex to replace space with a comma in the third field (`$3`):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{sub(/ /,",",$3)}1' file
12345,6789,Jim,Bob
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I will accept once the 10 minutes pass.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using `awk`

```
awk '$1=$1' OFS=, file
```

you get,

```
12345,6789,Jim,Bob
```

Comment: What is OFS, so that I know for the future?

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy OFS = Output Field Separator [Output Separators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Output-Separators.html)

Comment: Didn't think of that. ++

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling `sed` would be a lot faster for your requirement, given the huge size of the input file:

```
sed -E 's/ ([^ ]+)$/,\1/' file > file.modified
```

or, for in-place editing:

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/ ([^ ]+)$/,\1/' file
```

---

Benchmarking with a 36 MB file, dummy.txt:

```
$ time awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{sub(/ /,",",$3)}1' dummy.txt >/dev/null

real    0m3.357s
user    0m3.337s
sys 0m0.016s

$ time awk '{sub(/ /,",")}1' dummy.txt >/dev/null

real    0m3.182s
user    0m3.166s
sys 0m0.014s

$ time awk '$1=$1' OFS=, dummy.txt >/dev/null

real    0m3.150s
user    0m3.130s
sys 0m0.018s

$ time sed -E 's/ ([^ ]+)$/,\1/' dummy.txt >/dev/null

real    0m1.646s
user    0m1.633s
sys 0m0.013s
```

`sed` is 2x faster than `awk`!  For a 9G file, this difference could be even more dramatic.

Comment: For a file with 36MB, For me computer it's the opposite [view test here](http://i.imgur.com/DurPfih.png) .... `awk` is 2x faster than `sed` .... I find it more reasonable since it doesn't use `regex`

Comment: Confirmed, this was the faster method!

Comment: Even if you want speed, then I think nothing is faster than `tr ' ' ',' <dummy.txt`

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. - but OP wants the substitution only for the last field. He hasn't clarified whether other fields don't have spaces. If not for that, I think you are right about `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use '**tr**' also if that suits you

**`tr -s ' ' ',' < file.txt > tr.txt`**

where **file.txt** is your input file
and **tr.txt** is the output file.

Well if you want to use awk only, you could choose space as the field separator and use awk to print a ',' between two columns

```
awk -F' ' '{print $1","$2}' file.txt
```

Benchmarking done for 283Mb file

***Using tr***

```
time tr -s ' ' ',' < file.txt >tr.txt

real    0m10.976s
user    0m1.042s
sys     0m0.966s
```

***Using awk***

```
time awk -F' ' '{print $1","$2}' file.txt > /dev/null

real    0m14.141s
user    0m13.909s
sys     0m0.199s
```

***Using @codeforester method***

```
 time sed -E 's/ ([^ ]+)$/,\1/' file.txt >/dev/null

real    0m42.183s
user    0m41.659s
sys     0m0.435s
```

tr works even faster than sed and awk